# Is there a CSV import generator for Symfony?

Tags: php, csv, symfony1, import

This seems like an obvious thing, but I can't seem to find an implementation.

In the same way I can run:

```
./symfony doctrine:generate-admin backend MyModel
```

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
./symfony doctrine:generate-importer backend MyModel
```

Which would create a basic file upload for a CSV file, with headings matched to the column names.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: mysqlimport then regenerate the schema, models and forms

Comment: I'm looking to provide a means to import the data via a CSV file.  I don't want to change the models, etc.  This is for the client to be able to upload content en-masse.

Answer (score 2):

Ah sorry Colin i had the wrong end of the stick. There is this. 
[sfCsvPlugin - 0.1.2](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfCsvPlugin)

sfCsvReader: Reads a CSV file.
sfCsvWriter: Writes an array in CSV style.
sfCsvPropelWriter: Uses a sfCsvWriter to help you to dump data from your model through a Criteria object and doSelectRS method in CSV style.